# How to disable the tr and the controls inside that tr like gridview,imagebutton

Tags: asp.net

I have tr and inside tr, there are gridview and image button. I want to when i click activate/deactivate button, the the controls inside the tr get disabled and enabled. when disabled, i dont want to allow user to click on gridview and imagebutton.

Answer (score 0):

Make the  with runat="server", and setting the disabled property may trickle down to its children. Or, do:

```
<tr>
   <asp:Panel id="p1" runat="server">
       ctls
   </asp:Panel>
</tr>
```

And set the panel.enabled = false on the server will disable it...

If that doesn't help, could you provide more details?

HTH.